# C++ CLI Wrapper

Tags: c++-cli

I’ve a question about creating a C++ CLI Wrapper for a native C++ class to be used in C#.

Here is an example code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Wrapper {

    class NativeClass
    {
    public:
        NativeClass() {}
        int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a+b;
        }
    };

    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    public:
        Wrapper() {pNative = new NativeClass();}
        int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return(pNative->Add(a,b));
        }
        ~Wrapper()
        {
            delete pNative;
            pNative = 0;
        }
        !Wrapper()
        {
            this->~Wrapper();
        }
        //My problem is here.
        NativeClass* GetNative()
        {
            return pNative;
        }
    private:
        NativeClass* pNative;
    };
}
```

This code works fine. I need to retrieve the pointer that refers the native class to use it in the other wrapper classes. However, I don’t want the function “GetNative” to be visible in C# when I’m using this wrapper class. How can I hide it?

Comment: Try `internal:` as an access specifier.

Comment: If the other wrapper classes are in the same assembly, make the access `internal` instead of `public`.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do if they are not in the same assembly? (It is not my case, I just want to konw. Thank you very much)

Comment: Look into friend assemblies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the other wrapper classes are in the same assembly, make the access [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) instead of public. –  Roger Rowland Apr 25 '13 at 9:47

.

> if they are not in the same assembly? ...
>
> Look into [friend assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx) –  Sebastian Cabot Feb 1 at 15:43